# JSON Schema cross key constraint support using conditonal keywords

Tags: json, jsonschema

I want to express conditional validation of schema that contains cross key conditions. Is there a support for this in JSON schema with the available conditional keywords ( allOf/anyOf/if/then/else)

JSON Schema :

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
        "x": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "value": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "y": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "key1": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
                },
                "key2": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": ["x", "y", "m", "n", "r", "s"]
                }
            },
            "anyOf": [{
                    "allOf": [{
                            "if": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "key1": {
                                        "enum": ["a", "b"]
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "then": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "key2": {
                                        "enum": ["x", "y"]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "if": {
                                "x": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "value": {
                                            "const": "myVal"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "then": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "key2": {
                                        "enum": ["x", "y"]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "if": {
                        "properties": {
                            "key1": {
                                "enum": ["c", "d"]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "then": {
                        "properties": {
                            "key2": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "enum": ["m", "n"]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Sample JSON instance would look like this

```
{
    "x": {
        "value": "myVal"
    },
    "y": {
        "key1": "a",
        "key2": "x"
    }
}
```

The condition that I want to express is the following 2 conditions

1. **If** (x.value == "myVal" AND (y.key1 == "a" OR y.key1 == "b") **then** y.key2 should only have "x" or "y"
   (OR)
2. **If** ( y.key1 == "c" OR y.key1 == "d") **then** y.key2 should contain only "m" or "n".

   (OR)
3. y.key2 can take any of the allowed enum values defined in y.key2 property.

The conditional I have used the JSON Schema doesn't work. I tried validating using https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ .

Any help would be deeply appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: Should be able to help with this. Can you restructure your example data to include it as JSON? This will help create and demo the validation easier and quicker!

Comment: Also, you may try https://jsonschema.dev for faster browser based validation =]

Comment: At a glance, the likely cause is you're not expressing the `else` condition. It will be easier to explain with your data once ready

Comment: Thanks. I have put out the example in the following link https://jsonschema.dev/s/yya8x. The validation is the example given in the link should succeed by default, but fails.

My main challenge is to express condition that combines two outer level properties "x.value" and "y.key1" for for "y.key2"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I think this is one of those cases where it's better to forget about the `if`/`then`/`else` keywords and just define the good states in a `oneOf`.  (I suggest `oneOf` instead of `anyOf` because *exactly one* of these states should match.)

So for your schema, you want ONE OF

1. ALL OF

   - `x.value == "myVal"`
   - `y.key1 in ["a", "b"]`
   - `y.key2 in ["x", "y"]`
2. ALL OF

   - `y.key1 in ["c", "d"]`
   - `y.key2 in ["m", "n"]`
3. ALL OF

   - NOT

     - ONE OF

       - ALL OF

         - `x.value == "myVal"`
         - `y.key1 in ["a", "b"]`
       - `y.key1 in ["c", "d"]`
   - `true` (or `{}` if you're pre-draft-6)

It looks like you have #1 and #2 worked out; just drop the conditional logic.  It's the NOT in #3 that does the work.  Here we're saying that if the condition for #1 is false *and* the condition for #2 is false, then any value already defined in the enum for `y.key2` is fine.

The reason we have to explicitly express that we don't want the conditions for #1 and #2 is that without them, we just have a `true` schema, which allows everything (that's not previously constrained).

Now the other gotcha here is that you have `x` being used in one of your conditions, but your `anyOf` subschema is under the definition for `y`, so it can't see `x` at all.  To fix this, you'll want to move that subschema to the root, as a sibling to `properties`.  Here it can view the entire instance, not just the value in the `y` property.

Comment: Thanks much. Your suggestion worked.
.    Though I wonder why I couldn't use if/then/else ( trying to reduce the verbosity of the schema)